# Cálculo com horas em Excel não são muito precisos

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha que calcula as horas que um carro da empresa é utilizado em um mês.

a cada corrida é marcada hora inicial e hora final tomando intervalos de 30 minutos.

no final do mês tenho então uma tabela com as horas utilizadas de cada que são somadas para um total.

O problema é que da forma como o Excel calcula as horas, o resultado final acaba tendo uma pequena diferença de alguns segundos mesmo tendo todos os horários redondos.

Sendo assim, existe alguma forma de tornar esses cálculos melhores? Pois preciso de temos exatos porque utilizo esse resultado para fazer as cobranças dos respectivos departamentos.

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Apesar de ter explicado muito bem seria uma boa que você colocasse ao menos parte do seu código aqui, pois senão fica vago e dificulta para te ajudarmos. Aproveite e faça um [tour] pelo site e confira o guia de [ask].

Comment: Eu utilizo quase diariamente uma planilha para um "banco de horas" que faz totalização de tudo o que trabalhei no ano. Não tenho nenhum problema de precisão. Provavelmente é uma falha em suas fórmulas. Como disse o Math, seria interessante postar o código e/ou fórmulas que você utilizou.

Comment: @Math,@utluiz
Esqueci de mencionar que estou utilizando as horas no formato de números decimais pois tive problemas digitando no formato de hora (##:##). e como a conversão de números decimais para hora não é exata acaba dando essas diferenças.

Comment: faz a conta na mão 
hora mais hora + parte inteira da soma dos minutos/60
mais soma dos minutos modulo 60

Comment: Ainda assim, se você postar o seu código (ou, melhor ainda, um exemplo simples e funcional do seu problema) vai facilitar muitíssimo para que possamos lhe ajudar. :)

Comment: E ai cara, conseguiu solucionar seu problema?

Answer (score 4):

Cara, o excel trabalha de forma excelente com horas, você que talvez esteja trabalhando de forma errada com o excel.

Experimente formatar os campos como hora, e preencher o campo no seguinte formato HH:MM:SS (11:56:32). Em seguida basta você digitar a formula de um menos o outro

```
= A1 - B1
```

Ele irá te retornar o valor exato de tempo entre um e outro, caso esse horário possa ser maior que 24 horas, vá em formatar e escolha a opção que exibe na hora um valor maior que 24, exemplo:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

depois selecione a aba número, na lista clique em hora, em seguida na opção (ex: 37:30:55)

Tente manter esse metódo e não terás problemas com horas